# How to implement email/text notification if Spring Boot microservice loose the MSSQL DB connection

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, microservices, email-notifications

I have SpringBoot microservices which points to MSSQL (primary/secondary, no Listner) and getting DB connection from config engine. Below are the properties.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://{primarydb}:{port};databaseName={DBname};failoverPartner={secondarydb};databaseName={DBname}
spring.datasource.username={user}
spring.datasource.password={passwd}
```

Since we don't have Listner for our DB, when DBA switch primarydb our microservices start failing. Once we loose DB connection we should receive an email/phone text notification.
Can somebody please guide me how to acheive this?

As a workaround we restage those microservices in order to establish DB connection.
In future we are going to have Listner for our DB which will point to primary/secondary whichever is active.

Comment: Have you already investigated the spring.datasource.testonborrow or spring.datasource.testWhileIdle properties ? It could allow you to sent a valdiation query and uppon fail you could manage to catch the rror and plug whatever warning service you may want

Comment: Thanks @damus4 I will definitely try this.